# Difference between soap:address and jaxws:enpoint address

Tags: java, spring, wsdl, cxf

Like the title, I am new to `cxf`. Just wondering that what is the difference between the `soap:address`, and the address which is specified in `jaxws:endpoint` in application-context while publish it?

Furthermore, in the `jaxws:endpoint`, what is the difference between the address and publishedEndpointUrl?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 0):

`jaxws:endpoint` is a XML definition of `CXF` web service instead `soap:address` is a definition of `WSDL`.

CXF publish for you a Web Service instead WSDL is a contract that define the structure of WS. 
[Web Services Description Language](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language).

Furthermore

The attributes of the `jaxws:endpoint`. [Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Configuring_Web_Service_Endpoints/files/CXFDeployJAXWSEndpt.html)

**address**

> Specifies the address of an HTTP endpoint. This value overrides the
>   value specified in the services contract.

**publishedEndpointUrl**

> The URL that is placed in the address element of the generated WSDL.
>   If this value is not specified, the value of the address attribute is
>   used. This attribute is useful when the "public" URL is not be the
>   same as the URL on which the service is deployed.